# How to repeatedly change y when solving ODE dy/dt=f(t,y) with solve_ivp?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ode

When solving ODE dy/dt=f(t,y) with Scipy solve_ivp function, how do I repeatedly change the value of y at certain time points? For example, I would like to change y(t) to 0.5*y(t) when t = 0, 1, 2, 3....
One way to do this is to write many solve_ivp functions which run for time equals 1 and then take the output of the previous output and modify it (e.g. *0.5) to become the input of next solve_ivp function. But I am wondering if there is a more straightforward or easier way to do this kind of things? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `events` is what you are looking for, see the documentation for `solve_ivp`. It takes a little work to properly set up though.

Comment: This looks like a sensible solution. Jumps in the solution value correspond to Dirac-delta pulses as additional terms on the right. This are discontinuities that no solver is prepared to handle, directly or indirectly.

Comment: @PeterMeisrimel : As the jump time is known, no further root finding is necessary. It would be different if there was an event-action mechanism, but the "action" part is missing in scipy.

Comment: As Lutz Lehmann said, I also didn't find that events in solve_ivp can change the value of y itself. Am I wrong? @PeterMeisrimel

Comment: This is correct, the event mechanism in solve_ivp is strictly for finding roots of functions on the time-state space. One can locate the roots or stop at the first root, more functionality does not exist.

Comment: I submited an enhancement request for the `action`: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/19645